# Windows Phone 7 and WCF Video Service

Tags: wcf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to implement a service that will allow users to watch and upload videos to a WCF service from a windows phone 7 client (something like youtube). Now, I have the basic implementation of the service which sends video files (.wmv) to a client which has a MediaElement implementation of the Silverlight framework (has some differences from .NET implementation of the same class). Now, whenever I try to play the video locally on the client I get a SecurityException was unhandled error. When I try to encapsulate the service call in a try/catch block the application just hangs there.
Here's the code:

Server-side:

```
 class TransferService: ITransferService
    {
        public FileStream DownloadFile(string filename)
        {
            //string FilePath = Path.Combine(@"c:\Uploads", filename);

            FileStream result = File.Open(@"C:\Uploads\test.wmv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            return result;
        }

        public void UploadFile(FileStream request)
        {
            //Not yet implemented
        }
    }
```

Server-side(web.config):

```
    <configuration>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="100240" />
    </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" transferMode="Buffered">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="200000000"
                        maxArrayLength="200000000"
                        maxStringContentLength="200000000"
                        maxBytesPerRead="200000000"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="200000000"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="VideoService.TransferService" behaviorConfiguration="VideoServiceTypeBehaviors" >
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
        <endpoint contract="VideoService.ITransferService" binding="basicHttpBinding" address="basic" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="VideoServiceTypeBehaviors" >
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client-side:

```
    public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
        {
            TransferServiceClient sc;
            public Page1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                sc = new TransferServiceClient();
                this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Page_Loaded);
            }
            void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {

                sc.DownloadFileCompleted += new EventHandler<DownloadFileCompletedEventArgs>(sc_DownloadFileCompleted); //I think the problem is here
                sc.DownloadFileAsync("test.wmv");
            }
void sc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, DownloadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            myMediaElement.SetSource(e.Result);
            myMediaElement.Play();
        }
```

Client-side(ServiceReference.clientconfig):

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService" closeTimeout="00:02:00"
          openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00"
          maxBufferSize="210005536" maxReceivedMessageSize="210005536"
          textEncoding="utf-8">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:53163/TransferService.svc/basic"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService1"
        contract="TransferService.ITransferService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Any help or insight would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first i would try to use this code block correctly:

> sc.DownloadFileCompleted += new EventHandler(sc_DownloadFileCompleted); //I think the problem is here
>              sc.DownloadFileAsync("test.wmv");
>              myMediaElement.Play();

you fire up an asynchronous download-process and you are attaching a "download complete"-callback to it...
why do you call "myMediaElement.Play" synchronously AFTER the asynchronous invoke?
at this time, the file isn't downloaded yet and maybe the mediaelement fires the exception, because the file is locked (because of the download).

you have to call "myMediaElement" in the "sc_DownloadFileCompleted"-Handler AFTER the asynchronous download process finished....

please check if this was the prob...

Comment: I've made small changes in the code in my application (and also here), but it still doesn't work. I've put the myMediaElement.Play() method call in the event handler for the DownloadFileCompleted event. Didn't help...